# array.push adding key named push

Tags: javascript

What am I missing here? Shouldn't this just push 'hi' into the [4] instead of naming it with a key named 'push'?

```
<script>
    Array = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    Array.push = ('hi');
    console.log(Array);
</script>
```

Comment: [push is a method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), also you just overwrote the global `Array` constructor, by naming your variable `Array` and declaring it global scope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do like this -

```js
    var sampleArr = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    sampleArr.push('hi');
    console.log(sampleArr );
```

Comment: Why? Why are you overwriting the global `Array` object?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way would be :

```
var arr = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
arr.push('hi');
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
var array = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
array.push("hi");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp